# SQL (Redshift) - Find consecutive numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a table below:

```
ID  NUM
 1   1
 2   1
 3   1
 4   2
 5   3 
 6   1
```

I want to find which number(s) appears 3 times in a row. So in this example the output is 1.

How can I achieve this using regular SQL (not PL/SQL), when I have way much more rows in the data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a73d8/2)

```
select
    distinct num as ConsecutiveNums
from
(
    select
        num,
        count(*) as total
    from
    (
        select
            num,
            id - row_number() over (partition by num order by id) as rnk
        from myTable
    ) t
    group by
        num,
        rnk
) tt
where total > 2
```

Comment: @user12562215 this will give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select num
from (select t.*,
             lag(num) over (order by id) as num_1,
             lag(num, 2) over (order by id) as num_2
      from t
     ) t
where num_1 = num and num_2 = num;
```

Here is another fun method:

```
select num
from (select t.*,
             lag(id, 2) over (order by id) as id_2_by_id,
             lag(id, 2) over (partition by num order by id) as id_2_by_id_num
      from t
     ) t
where num = id_2_by_id_num and num_2_by_id = id_2_by_id_num;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I think I need to assume that I don't know the answer is 1. I need to find out what the number is. So in the WHERE statement I can't put num = 1 as the condition.

Comment: @user12562215 . . . That is easily adjusted by comparing the values to each other, rather than to `1`.